# How to instrument New Relic for Rack app?

Tags: ruby, rack, newrelic

Instead of seeing the web requests like `POST /foo`, I see only `App#call` for a Rack app.

How to set up New Relic instrumentation for each HTTP request?

Answer (score 1):

```
class App
  def self.call env
    NewRelic::Agent.set_transaction_name "#{ env[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ]} #{ env[ 'PATH_INFO' ]}", category: :sinatra
```

It is not necessary to tell New Relic to instrument the call method because it does that automatically.

I set a transaction name because otherwise the name of all transactions is "call".